# Qt Location API still available?

Tags: qt, qt-mobility

In [Qt Location API page at Nokia](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Qt_Location_API) website, [the link to SDK's download](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/da8df288-e615-443d-be5c-00c8a72435f8/Qt_SDK.html) requires login by using my existing account on their web site but keeps saying "Singing in..." and never returns. Anybody has an idea? Has `Nokia` / `Degia` shutdown the project?

---

**Update**) I'm intending desktop app for a large scale opensource framework in robotics. I'll start from `Ubuntu` but should support multiple desktop OSs.

Comment: What platform are you developing for?

Comment: Qt Location was going to be a full add-on module for Qt5, but it seems to be [undergoing some rework](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23659). You can find the current state of the module at in the [Qt Mobility repository](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-mobility). If you're developing for Symbian or MeeGo, I have no idea what you're supposed to do, since those platforms are no longer supported.

Comment: @Slavik81 that sounds like an answer at this moment. Why not move it to Answer section so that I can select it as an answer?

Comment: Did you end up getting Qt Mobility to work in your desktop environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt Location was going to be a full add-on module for Qt 5.0, but it was cut and reworked instead. As of Qt 5.5, [Qt Location is listed as a Technology Preview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmodules.html), which suggests it will be a standard module soon.

[Here's a couple quotes](https://web.archive.org/web/20140809213922/http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23659/) about why it was cut and how it was reworked:

> Unfortunately, some modules either lost their maintainers, or their
>   quality was not up to scratch, so they were excluded from the Qt 5.0.0
>   release. Qt Location did not make the cut, and its code base still
>   requires lots of cleaning up.
>
> The plan is to include those modules when they are ready though.

-

> A lot of the components in Qt Location have been converted to value
>   types. Previously components such as Coordinate, GeoCircle,
>   GeoRectangle etc were QObjects. Now they are value types which
>   provides a much nicer API.

By the way, Nokia is no longer involved in the development of Qt. I would not recommend downloading an old SDK from Nokia. You can get the most recent release from http://qt.io/download

Comment: Do recent releases of Qt, Qt5 and newer, come with the mobility modules or do we have to build them from the repo?

Comment: @mdoran3844 The current version of Qt [doesn't list it as an included module](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/qtmodules.html). I believe you will need to build it yourself.